# Are captureless lambda guaranteed to be empty by the standard?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, c++20

I'm searching for a way to identify empty (captureless) lambdas from other lambdas in a template function. I'm currently using C++17 but I'm curious for C++20 answers too.

My code looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
auto func(T lambda) {
    // The aguments of the lambdas are unknown

    if constexpr (/* is captureless */) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Is it guaranteed by the C++ standard (17 or 20) that a captureless lambda, which is convertible to a function pointer, will also make [`std::is_empty`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_empty) yield true?

Take this code as an example:

```
auto a = []{}; // captureless
auto b = [c = 'z']{}; // has captures

static_assert(sizeof(a) == sizeof(b)); // Both are the same size
static_assert(!std::is_empty_v<decltype(b)>); // It has a `c` member
static_assert(std::is_empty_v<decltype(a)>); // Passes. It is guaranteed?
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/BcMz7s)

Comment: If you only care about non-template lambdas, you could use SFINAE to check if conversion to a function pointer (`+lambda`) is well-formed.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I thought about that, but as far as I remember, MSVC don't allow that since they overloaded the conversion operator.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot MS exposes a separate conversion operator for all available calling conventions. Just pick one and try to convert the lambda to a comparable function pointer, and check if that succeeds or fails.

Comment: `+` seems to work [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/VNrTnq).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, in fact, the standard explicitly grants permission for lambdas to have a size that doesn't line up with their declaration.  [[expr.prim.lambda.closure]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.lambda#closure-2) states

> The closure type is declared in the smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace scope that contains the corresponding lambda-expression. [ Note: This determines the set of namespaces and classes associated with the closure type ([basic.lookup.argdep]). The parameter types of a lambda-declarator do not affect these associated namespaces and classes. — end note ] The closure type is not an aggregate type. **An implementation may define the closure type differently from what is described below provided this does not alter the observable behavior of the program other than by changing:**
>
> - **the size and/or alignment of the closure type,**
> - whether the closure type is trivially copyable ([class.prop]), or
>   (2.3)
> - whether the closure type is a standard-layout class ([class.prop]).
>
> An implementation shall not add members of rvalue reference type to the closure type.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

So this allows the implementation to give the lambda a member even if it is capture-less.  I don't think any implementation ever would, but they are legally allowed to do so.